# Fastlane lane uploading application to testflight

Tags: ios, react-native, fastlane

I am trying to build an ios application and upload it to Testflight using Fastlane but I'm getting these errors. appName is the name of my application.

```
[04:32:03]: $ set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace ./appName.xcworkspace -scheme appName -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath /Users/distiller/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-05-01/appName\ 2020-05-01\ 04.32.03.xcarchive archive | tee /Users/distiller/Library/Logs/gym/appName-appName.log | xcpretty

[04:32:05]: ▸ ❌  error: /Users/distiller/demo-react-native/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-appName/Pods-appName.release.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "appName" in project "appName") (in target 'appName')

[04:32:05]: ▸ ❌  error: /Users/distiller/demo-react-native/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-appName/Pods-appName.release.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "appName" in project "appName") (in target 'appName')

[04:32:05]: ▸ ❌  error: /Users/distiller/demo-react-native/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-appName/Pods-appName.release.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "appName" in project "appName") (in target 'appName')

[04:32:05]: ▸ ❌  error: Failed to parse IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET: Could not parse version component from: '3 ' (in target 'appName')

[04:32:05]: ▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **


❌  error: /Users/distiller/demo-react-native/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-appName/Pods-appName.release.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "appName" in project "appName") (in target 'appName')




❌  error: /Users/distiller/demo-react-native/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-appName/Pods-appName.release.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "appName" in project "appName") (in target 'appName')




❌  error: /Users/distiller/demo-react-native/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-appName/Pods-appName.release.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "appName" in project "appName") (in target 'appName')




❌  error: Failed to parse IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET: Could not parse version component from: '3 ' (in target 'appName')



** ARCHIVE FAILED **

[04:32:05]: Exit status: 65

[04:32:05]: 

[04:32:05]: Maybe the error shown is caused by using the wrong version of Xcode

[04:32:05]: Found multiple versions of Xcode in '/Applications/'

[04:32:05]: Make sure you selected the right version for your project

[04:32:05]: This build process was executed using '/Applications/Xcode-10.1.app'

[04:32:05]: If you want to update your Xcode path, either

[04:32:05]: 

[04:32:05]: - Specify the Xcode version in your Fastfile

[04:32:05]: ▸ xcversion(version: "8.1") # Selects Xcode 8.1.0

[04:32:05]: 

[04:32:05]: - Specify an absolute path to your Xcode installation in your Fastfile

[04:32:05]: ▸ xcode_select "/Applications/Xcode8.app"

[04:32:05]: 

[04:32:05]: - Manually update the path using

[04:32:05]: ▸ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app

[04:32:05]: 


+---------------+------------------------------+

|              Build environment               |

+---------------+------------------------------+

| xcode_path    | /Applications/Xcode-10.1.app |

| gym_version   | 2.146.1                      |

| export_method | app-store                    |

| sdk           | iPhoneOS12.1.sdk             |

+---------------+------------------------------+


[04:32:05]: ▸ Build system information

[04:32:05]: ▸ error: /Users/distiller/demo-react-native/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-appName/Pods-appName.release.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "appName" in project "appName") (in target 'appName')

[04:32:05]: ▸ Build system information

[04:32:05]: ▸ error: Failed to parse IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET: Could not parse version component from: '3 ' (in target 'appName')

[04:32:05]: 

[04:32:05]: ⬆️  Check out the few lines of raw `xcodebuild` output above for potential hints on how to solve this error

[04:32:05]:   For the complete and more detailed error log, check the full log at:

[04:32:05]:   /Users/distiller/Library/Logs/gym/appName-appName.log

[04:32:05]: 

[04:32:05]: Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project

[04:32:05]: It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how

[04:32:05]: to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/

[04:32:05]: Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make

[04:32:05]: sure your project is set up correctly.

[04:32:05]: fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the

[04:32:05]: the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.

[04:32:05]: Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there
```

Comment: Does the app compile without using fastlane?

Comment: yes the app compiles fine in xcode.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @ghkatende how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because `pod install` failed for you, or something else went wrong while installing dependencies.

---

I spent an entire day on this today, only for my colleague to point out that my `pod install` command was failing earlier in the build.

```
18:40:00  + cd app/ios
18:40:00  + pod install --repo-update
18:40:00  ./install.sh: /usr/local/bin/pod: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
18:40:00  + cd ../../
```

On seeing this, it was clear that this was a problem with my Ruby environment. I had updated ruby in the system (to 2.6.3), and I was still seeing a reference to the older version (2.3) in these logs.